# Отладка java for web

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, отладка

Пытаюсь писать серверную часть на Java.
Развернул maven-проект со Spring MVC, вникаю в мануал.
По итогу запуска получаю 404 вместо чего-то хорошего(отрендеренного view).

Суть вопроса: как самому понять где ошибка, и продебажить код?
Интересно взглянуть на trace вызовов или понять почему именно 404.
(на каком месте в коде эта 404 банально возникла)

Comment: Включить логирование и посмотреть в лог. Скорей всего у вас какие-то бины не загрузились и поэтому 404.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman расскажите подробнее как

Comment: создайте новый вопрос

Comment: @MikhailVaysman мне кажется что этот вопрос именно об этом - как включить логгирование и хоть что-то отдебажить

Comment: Вопрос как отлаживать. Я предложил вариант, но это не ответ на ваш вопрос и поэтому это комментарий, а не ответ.